# A question related to convergence in distribution (Clarification in answer is needed)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image: Question]

[image: Answer]

Above you see the question and its answer taken from the Solution Manual. However, I couldn't understand the solution properly. How are we able to choose such an "$m$"? How do we construct the last expression given in the answer above? I am open to any clarification. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are several errors, possibly typos,  in the Solution Manual.

Comment: Like what? if you could share, i would be happy.